# Trying in vertically center p in div with Genesis classes

Tags: wordpress, vertical-alignment, genesis

I am trying to vertically center a paragraph next to an image that uses Genesis column classes in WordPress. Each is in a separate column (code below). I tried `display:table-cell;` `inline-block;` `vertical-align:middle`. Could it be something to do with Genesis classes or WordPress in general? My question seems similar to [How do I vertically align text next to img in Genesis columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363002/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-img-in-genesis-columns)
 asked by Metzed on October 14, 2014 but I tried that solution and it didn't work either.

```
<div class="one-fourth first">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/placeholder8.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="three-fourths">
    <p>Paragraph text here.</p>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I'm just using the general genesis classes contained below:

```
.one-fourth {
    width: 23.076923076923077%;
}

.three-fourths {
    width: 74.35897435897436%;
}

.first {
    clear: both; margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: please post the css code in your question

Comment: I'm just using the general genesis classes contained below:

.one-fourth {
 width: 23.076923076923077%;
}

.three-fourths {
 width: 74.35897435897436%;
} .first {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 0;
}

Comment: Maybe try Flex? CSS Flex